# Parameter definition syntax - how to read the parameter info popup in IDE

Tags: syntax, parameters, ide

As a beginner and to learn faster i would like to get a better understanding of
the syntax of the parameter popup in my IDE.

Example:
.catch....
will show ...
Parameter popup: "onrejected?:((reason:any)=>(PromiseLike | any)) | undefined |null"

1. Which topics should i learn early to understand the syntax (Arrow
   functions,...)?
2. There seem to be also some kind of keywords and specific structure. Where can i find documentation/help on the parameter syntax?

Comment: Add which ide and language to make this question more clear.

Comment: Intellij, VS code, Webstorm.... java, javaSript....
Carefull... i am not asking about this special Popup! 
This was just an example.
I am asking about the general syntax rules.